# What type of screw driver do I need for this type of small socket 5 sided star screw?

Tags: hardware

I'm trying to open up an electronic device with the following 5 sided star screw nut. I need a precision 5 sided socket screw driver and I cant seem to find the correct one. How would one find the correct tool for these type of screws when we never have encountered them before? Is there a scientific method of calling these screws so we can find the correct tool easily?

(ex. Pentagon Star nut screw?)

[image]

Comment: It is not uncommon for manufacturers to use a specially sourced screw that needs a special tool to insert / remove (and available only to them) depending on the piece of equipment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  this is not EE

Comment: Your photograph is extremely unclear. Since this is basically the only content of your question, I strongly encourage you to replace it with one that allows the screw to be identified unambiguously.

Comment: here's a clearer one: http://prntscr.com/ao2ejf -- i would need a socket screw driver as its not the typical star one found on macbooks.

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, ***tamper-proof TORX Plus.***

[image]

For this

[image]

Or ***Pentalobe***, a mainly Apple thing.

[image]

Some places simply call it Star screws/heads. Check for security bit sets. I've gotten some at a dollar store, home depot, lowes, ebay, the usual places.

If you don't care about saving the screw, any common screw extractor set will work.

[You could also try the melted bic pen method.](http://atariage.com/forums/topic/197812-how-to-open-snes/?p=2528494)

Comment: thanks. but here's a clearer picture. http://prntscr.com/ao2ejf -- its not the typical screws you find on a macbook.

Answer (score 2):

You generally have two fairly binary choices for security screws as seen in Passerby's excellent answer (+1). You can get a scuzzy set of dubious bits for cheap in a flea market, eBay, ali (but I repeat myself), Harbor Freight (USA), Princess Auto (Canada) etc. or you get an official driver for perhaps 10-100x as much that is made to spec and properly hardened to last for years driving screws every day.

Usually the cheap ones are okay enough for DIY projects. Sometimes you can get them in a set with plastic pry tools ("spudgers") that assist in opening the case of the device in question (usually there are a few screws and a bunch of snaps around the outside holding the bezel or case together- you will probably need to carefully pry the case to get the snaps to let go without breaking them- or marring the case excessively).  See, for example, this [web](http://journeytojustus.com/2015/07/14/repairing-my-phone-lcd/) page:

[image: http://journeytojustus.com/2015/07/14/repairing-my-phone-lcd/]

Answer (score 1):

That's a very blurry picture, but generally five pointed screws are either [pentalobe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentalobe_screw) (Apple's thing) or 5 point Star Torx, which are tamper proof screws, typically with a post in the middle. Searching either term will pull up loads of results on your online retailer of choice.

Answer (score 0):

The general term for this type of screw is **security screw** or **tamper-proof screw**. You will need a security screwdriver, they are often sold in kits with 30-50 different types of bit.

Answer (score 0):

My ham-fisted approach usually works quite well, even if it is a little bit unorthodox.

Apply a bit of solder flux to the screw head, then heat with a soldering iron until solder will flow.  Add a decent-size blob of solder so that you get a nice round surface.  Sort of like a ball of solder sitting on top of the screw head.

Then, while the solder is still molten, stick a slot screwdriver blade into the solder blob and hold it still until the solder hardens.  Be sure to not let anything move while the solder is hardening or the solder will crystallize and you will have to reheat the solder and do it again.

When the solder is thoroughly hardened, GENTLY turn the screw out.  Redo the whole flux - heating process if necessary.

This technique works quite well for those screws in locations where you can get a soldering iron to the screw head.  I have found it to be quite effective on screws into plastic, somewhat effective for screws into metal.

Comment: The plastic casing looks to be ABS or something like that. I would use epoxy instead of solder, in order to avoid destroying the casing. (It is also stronger than solder.) Stainless steel screws may also require zinc chloride flux, which is seriously corrosive.